# git/EGit loses remote configuration

Tags: git, egit, git-remote

EGit loses remote configuration.

I have such Remotes configuration (2 remotes):

[image: 1st]

But in the morning I get again (origin point to /PaulVI):

[image: 2nd]

`git remote` output:

```
C:\Users\weibl\Documents\GitHub\nodeclipse-2 [master]> git remote -v
PaulVI  https://github.com/PaulVI/nodeclipse-2.git (fetch)
PaulVI  https://github.com/PaulVI/nodeclipse-2.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/PaulVI/nodeclipse-2.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/PaulVI/nodeclipse-2.git (push)
```

Comment: There are three config files (one in the repo, on in `~/.gitconfig` and one where git is installed). Is it possible that the local repo config did overwrite the one in HOME?

Comment: No ~/.gitcongif; used msysgit has no configuration for repositories in C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\gitconfig

Comment: Ok, just checking. Not sure why EGit would do a `git remote set-url origin <newurl>`. What version of Eclipse, Egit, java, and OS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is [GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/).

On start-up it updates `origin`'s value for repositories in ~\Documents\GitHub.

[image]